# How to pop up a customize message when get() function fails to locate element in cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

In cypress I'm able to pop up a assert message when get() is good and contain() or ep() fails with custom overwrite should command. But not able to figure if get() fails to locate element.

Can we overwrite the get() function.

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('should', (originalFn, assertion, expected, options) => {
  if (options && options.message) {
    cy.removeAllListeners('fail') // remove all 'fail' listeners
    // And we're starting from fresh!
    cy.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
      error.name = 'CustomError'
      error.message = options.message
      throw error // throw error to have test still fail
    })
  }

  return originalFn( assertion, expected, options)
})

it('fails with custom message via overwrite of should', () => {
cy.wrap(1).should('eq', 1, { message: 'custom error message 1'})
cy.wrap(1).should('eq', 2, { message: 'custom error message 2'})
```

})

Answer (score 0):

The code you presented is incorrect, there are five parameters to the overwrite

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('should', (originalFn, actual, assertion, expected, options)
  // actual = 1
  // assertion = eq
  // expected = 2
  // options = { message: ... }
  ... // now the rest of the code works - sort of
```

Note that `cy.on('fail',...` continues to operate after the current command and current test, unless explicitly overwritten.